# Cauchy sequence in a complete Riemannian manifold

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, $N\subset M$ a closed submanifold, $p\in M\setminus N$ and $d(p,N)$ the distance from $N$ to $p$. I would like to show that there exists a point $q\in N$ such that $d(p,q)=d(p,N)$.

Question: does there always exist a Cauchy sequence $(q_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\subset N$ such that $d(p,q_i)\to d(p,N)$?

If so, the completeness of $M$ (and thus of $N$) would imply that the sequence $(q_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to some $q\in N$ such that $d(p,q)=d(p,N)$, as desired.

How do I find such a sequence? Is the existence a property of complete metric spaces?

Comment: The $d$ of $M$ and $N$ are the same ? So the sequence $q_i \in N$ such that $d(p,q_i) \to d(p,N)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Yes, the distances are the same. My question is why the sequence $q_i\in N$ such that $d(p,q_i)\to d(p,N)$ exists. I think this is a basic fact about metric spaces that I am forgetting. Thanks

Comment: That's the definition of $d(p,N)$ as $\inf_{q \in N} d(p,q)$. Then use that  bounded sequences on $N$ (ie. $d(q_1,q_n) \le C$) have a convergent subsequence (because Riemannian manifolds are locally compact) and $d(p,q_n) \le C'$ implies $d(q_1,q_n) \le C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q\in N$ and $G$ be a closed geodesic ball with center at $p$ and radius $r=d(p,q)$. The intersection $A$ of $G$ and $N$ is compact and consequently the function $d(p,q_i)$ restricted to $A$ attains its minimum in $A$.